# Run iocage exec with multiple commands

Tags: bash

Instead of calling iocage exec multiple times, like bellow:

```
iocage exec "${JAIL_NAME}" chown 0:0 /settings/ipfw_rules
iocage exec "${JAIL_NAME}" chmod 600 /settings/ipfw_rules
iocage exec "${JAIL_NAME}" sysrc "firewall_enable=YES"
iocage exec "${JAIL_NAME}" sysrc "firewall_type=/settings/ipfw_rules"
iocage exec "${JAIL_NAME}" sysrc "openvpn_enable=YES"
iocage exec "${JAIL_NAME}" sysrc "openvpn_dir=/settings"
...
```

Can I use something like this?

```
cat <<-EOF | iocage exec "${JAIL_NAME}"
    chown 0:0 /settings/ipfw_rules
    chmod 600 /settings/ipfw_rules
    sysrc "firewall_enable=YES"
    sysrc "firewall_type=/settings/ipfw_rules"
    sysrc "openvpn_enable=YES"
...
EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'xargs' to construct command from standard input:

```
cat <<-EOF | xargs -L1 iocage exec "${JAIL_NAME}"
  Command Here
...
EOF
```